# doc.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jstree

On my page I'm rendering a tree based on jsTree angular directive. I'm trying to achieve a showing tooltip on hover for particularly node which has a description field. I have checked list of API for jsTree and have found on hover event listener `hover_node`, with help angular directive for jsTree I have setup my scope function to this listener

```
 <js-tree
         tree-data="scope"
         tree-model="tree"
         tree-events="hover_node:nodeHovered"
         tree-core="tree_core"
></js-tree>

 $scope.nodeHovered = function (e, data) {

      var dataNode  = data.node;
      var original = dataNode.original;

      if (typeof original.description !== 'undefined'){

        var nodeDescription = original.description;

           $(original).tooltip({
              title: nodeDescription,
              animation: true
           });
         }
     };
```

My function works well when I hover on any node, I can see the object data in console, so I wrote a piece of code which allows to see the description in console if typeof node description is not an equal undefined. It works well for console but when I added function bootstrap tooltip for this node that to show the description as tooltip, I've got next error

> Uncaught TypeError: doc.addEventListener is not a function

As I could understand from some topics here, the nature of this mistake is arrays don't have addEventListener function, but I'm working with an object which is already defined thru the library, so could anybody help to find what I'm missing? I appreciate any help.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ZNILEawoznPrIq7aHZK?p=preview)

my full code

```
   var treeFolders = [];
   $scope.tree = [];


    $http.get("folders.json")
          .then(function (res) {
              treeFolders = res.data;
              angular.forEach(treeFolders, function(obj){
                   if(!("parent" in obj)){
                        obj.parent = "#";
                            }
                        })
                    })

   $scope.load = function(){
                $scope.tree = treeFolders
            };


   $scope.tree_core = {
                multiple: false,  // disable multiple node selection
                check_callback: function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
                return true;  // allow all other operations
                },
                themes : {
                    theme : "default",
                    dots : true,
                    icons : true
                }
            };

   $scope.nodeHovered = function (e, data) {

      var dataNode  = data.node;
      var original = dataNode.original;

      if (typeof original.description !== 'undefined'){

        var nodeDescription = original.description;

           $(original).tooltip({
              title: nodeDescription,
              animation: true
           });
         }
     };
```

html

```
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="load()">Load Tree</button>

   <js-tree
           tree-data="scope"
           tree-model="tree"
           tree-events="hover_node:nodeHovered"
           tree-core="tree_core"
></js-tree>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `original` object that you are passing to jQuery in the following code is a jsTree node, not a DOM element:

```
$(original).tooltip({
  title: nodeDescription,
  animation: true
});
```

Instead use the `get_node` method of jsTree to retrieve the jQuery wrapped DOM element from the node:

```
var liElement = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true);
```

This will give you the entire `li` element, but you probably want the tooltip placed relative to the `a` element:

```
var aElement = liElement.children('a').first();
```

Then:

```
aElement.tooltip({
  title: nodeDescription,
  animation: true
}).tooltip('show');
```

Note that I have added an extra call to `tooltip` at the end. This is for the tooltip to be shown the first time the element is hovered. Without this the tooltip would be created on the first hover, then not shown until the next.

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/itMSrsroTVswD3RLbs7O?p=preview